# How to detect status of a Like button change outside my page

Tags: facebook-like

I am implementing like button in my page an can detect if user likes/unlikes with JS events. Is there a way to detect if user unlikes within Facebook (not from web page). OR a way to detect the status of button when the page first loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really without asking for app permissions from each user who visits your site and looking at their likes connection via the Graph API.